# Crystal Reports - Select distinct records in group

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to show distinct records in groups in crystal reports.  The view I wrote returns something like this:

```
Field 1  |  Field 2  |   Field 3
----------------------------------
    10   |   111     |  Record Info 1
    10   |   111     |  Record Info 1
    10   |   222     |  Record Info 2
    20   |   111     |  Record Info 1
    20   |   222     |  Record Info 2
```

The report groups are based off field one, and I want distinct fields 2 and 3 for each group:

```
Field 1  |  Field 2  |   Field 3
----------------------------------
    10   |   111     |  Record Info 1
    10   |   222     |  Record Info 2
    20   |   111     |  Record Info 1
    20   |   222     |  Record Info 2
```

Field 2 and 3 are always the same, Field 1 acts as an FK reference to any entries in the view.  Selecting `distinct xxx` in the view isn't really viable due to the huge amount of columns being brought in.

Can this be done in CR?

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you group by field 1, field 2 and field3 in query? that way ur duplicate rows will be removed and then pull it in CR.

Comment: check the "Select Distinct Data for Browsing" from ReportOption in Report menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a group for field1, field2
2. Hide Details area, field1 group area header and field1 group footer
3. Drop all the columns you want to show in the field2 group area header/footer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You might also consider using `Database | Select Distinct Records`.